# Scroll color js

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have use a js for changing scroll color in all browser. in my site till the time whole page is not loaded the scroll bar is occur as by default and when page is fully refreshed then the scrollbar is ocuur through js. now i want then the mediator scrollbar should not be seen during refresh of site. the scrollbar which is come from js should seen during refresh of page. means i have to remove default scrollbar during refresh of page.

Comment: this has nothing to do with php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS, add "display:none" to the rule for "div#ycustomscroll2_vscrollerbase".  I did it for you in the inline style as shown below:

```
      <div id="mycustomscroll2_vscrollerbase" 
          class="display:none;  vscrollerbase scrollgeneric" 
          style="visibility: visible; height: 355px; left: 494px;  ">
```

Then, unhide the element when the page loads as follows:

```
     $(document).ready( function() {
         $('div#ycustomscroll2_vscrollerbase').css('display','block');
     });
```